# spring batch group validate input lines from FlatFileItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-admin

I have a spring batch job where in I use FlatFileItemReader and populate it to Pojo objects  (items). My file has a footer line that gives me the number of records in the file. I need to validate that my List has that many objects.

I cannot do it through ItemProcessor as it gives me only one item at a time. Is there any other way to do such a validation in spring batch?

Thanks
Paddy

Comment: can you describe what you mean by "i need to validate that my List has that many objects"

Comment: Yes, if my flat file has 80 records excluding header and tail. My trail record will give me the count 80 for the field recordCount. Each record is identified as Header , trail or data record by key H, T and R respectively in a field recordType. I need a way to get the whole list of records in a method, iterate through it and see if the count of records with recordType as R is 80.

Comment: Is there any issue in using Item Reader listener and Job Execution context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring's FlatFileItemReader provides a feature to skip the number of line at the top and end. This issue got solved using them. Don't have a postable code, but was led to the answer from the the reader writer documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html